# Pointers to the same address are different from each other

Tags: c++

I recently got curious about pointers and I cannot understand why the following doesn't work.

My idea is to create a variable, say its address (in decimal), ask the user to input it back and take that as the address for a pointer which points to the previous variable. In the end both variables should have the same value.

The last pointer points to supposedly, a bad memory address because it segfaults, but when I print the address of the pointers they are the same!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int temp = 0;
    printf("Temporary integer addr 0x%x (dec %d)\n", &temp, &temp);

    int input = -1;
    printf("Give me an address to read (in dec)\n");
    std::cin >> input;
    printf("You chose the number %d (hex 0x%x)\n", input, input);

    int* intPtr = (int*)input;
    int* tempPtr = &temp;

    if (intPtr == tempPtr) {
        printf("It works, they are equal!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Expected: 0x%x got 0x%x\n", tempPtr, intPtr);
        printf("Expected value: 0x%d got 0x%d", temp, *intPtr); // segfaults
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the console output

```
Main function addr 0xb0ddf7d0 (dec -1327630384)
Temporary integer addr 0xb0ddf7c8 (dec -1327630392)
Give me an address to read (in dec)
-1327630392
You chose the number -1327630392 (hex 0xb0ddf7c8)
Expected: 0xb0ddf7c8 got 0xb0ddf7c8

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

What is wrong with it? How can I create a pointer that points to the address the user inputs?
I compiled it on g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127

Comment: I wonder if gcc is assuming undefined behavior somewhere, so assuming the pointers never match, so removing the check entirely?

Comment: Also, this isn't a minimal example. There's no reason for the `mainPtr` lines

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was something I should've removed

Comment: What happens if you declare your `input` variable as `long long int`?

Comment: Try with `std::uintptr_t` instead of `int`, as it's guaranteed to fit a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior. First of all, the format specifier `%x` will cause `printf` to expect an argument of type `unsigned int`. However, you're passing it an argument of type `int*`. You'd want to use `%p` for printing that. Most likely, you're working on a 64-Bit machine, which means that addresses will be 64 Bits wide. An `int` will almost certainly not be large enough to represent all possible addresses. While passing an argument of one type to a function that will interpret the value of that argument as the wrong type is generally undefined behavior, what will most likely happen here in practice is that `printf` is simply going to print just the lower couple of Bits of your pointer value interpreted as an `unsigned int`. You then have your user type back in what is effectively only the lower half of your actual address, cast that back to a pointer, and access that memory location, which is almost certainly not going to be a valid address of an object of type `int`. That's where you get undefined behavior all over again (luckily, this time manifesting itself in a segfaul).

If you want an integer that can represent a pointer value, use, e.g., [`std::uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). Also, just don't use C-style casts in C++. They are there for backwards compatibility with C code. There is no advantage to C-style casts but a lot of disadvantages (see, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427107/c-style-cast-vs-reinterpret-cast), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359961/c-difference-between-reinterpret-cast-and-c-style-cast), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831696/reinterpret-cast-vs-c-style-cast), or [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50442/c-style-casts-or-c-style-casts) question for more). Also, `printf` is not type safe, don't use `printf`. Your question is yet another testimony to that (see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c) for more). If you had used `std::cout` instead, your pointer would have automatically been printed correctly. In general, `printf` expects you to take care of making sure the types of arguments that are actually passed matche the types specified in your format string. If you make any mistake at all, you end up in undefined behavior land. `std::cout`, on the other hand, will either do the right thing or fail to compile. Finally, I just can't help myself but note how really, really weird it is to see `std::cin` being used for input next to `printf` being used for output…

Comment: I saw the internal variables had enough bits, but failed to notice that `%x` was truncating in the output. Well done!

Comment: @ybungalobill on 64-Bit systems, the first couple integer and pointer arguments are generally passed in registers, not on the stack…

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I didn't have in mind 64 bit... After using 64 bit ints it works, thank you.

Comment: @ybungalobill it does on all systems I'm aware of.

Comment: @JaimeMartinezRincon best use `std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t` whenever you need an integer type that is *always* guaranteed to be able to represent a pointer value (ideally, that would be never ;-). Simply switching to some 64-Bit integer type solves the problem only for a particular set of target platforms…

Comment: @ybungalobill I [tried it](https://godbolt.org/z/VEaipx). GCC just loads `&temp` into `%rbx`, then copies `%rbx` to `%rdx` and `%rsi` before calling `printf`. No stack pushing.

Answer (score 2):

`int` won't store a pointer on a 64 bit architecture. Usually you'll need `long`s (on LP64 architectures; `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide anywhere), or portably the `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` typedef defined in `stdint.h`/`cstdint` if they're available.

If you need a larger type than `int` and you use `int`, the addresses will get truncated.

This is working for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    void* mainPtr = (void*) &main;
    printf("Main function addr 0x%" PRIxPTR " (" PRIdPTR " %ld)\n", (uintptr_t)&mainPtr, (uintptr_t)&mainPtr);

    int temp = 0;
    printf("Temporary integer addr 0x%" PRIxPTR " (dec %" PRIdPTR ")\n", (uintptr_t)&temp, (uintptr_t)&temp);

    uintptr_t input = -1;
    printf("Give me an address to read (in dec)\n");
    std::cin >> input;
    printf("You chose the number %" PRIdPTR " (hex 0x%" PRIxPTR ")\n", input, input);

    int* intPtr = (int*)input;
    int* tempPtr = &temp;

    if (intPtr == tempPtr) {
        printf("It works, they are equal!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Expected: 0x%" PRIxPTR " got 0x%" PRIdPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)tempPtr, (uintptr_t)intPtr);
        printf("Expected value: 0x%d got 0x%d", temp, *intPtr); // segfaults
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the portable way to print these special `typedefs` is with
the `PRIxPTR` and similar macros defined int `inttypes.h`/`cinttypes`, relying on string literal concatenation if you want to use stdio (C++'s `std::cout <<` should print them with less hustle).

Comment: On my GCC (targeting x86_64) `long` is 4 bytes. Why not `uintptr_t` instead?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'll fix it up

Comment: @HolyBlackCat By GCC do you refer to MinGW? Are there other x86_64 systems besides Windows that have 32 bit `long`?

Comment: @eerorika Yup, it's MinGW.

Comment: Portable programs should never ever use `long int`. Either `int` or `long long int`. I worked in a place where having `long int` would trigger a hard validation error on commit.

Comment: @SergeyA What if I want an integer type that can portably hold 32-bit values? `long long int` would be overkill.

Comment: @melpomene `int32_t` will be your choice.

Comment: @SergeyA `int32_t` isn't required to exist.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, portable programs should use `{,u}intptr_t` I guess. My first draft didn't have them cuz I had to look up the printf formatter for these `typedefs`.

Comment: @PSkocik my observation was generic, not tied to use of integers as holders of pointers.

Comment: @melpomene `long int` is not required to be 32 bits, could be more than that. I guess, it is easy to define `int32_t` for your platform as an alias for `long int` if it is, indeed, 32 bits.

Comment: @SergeyA And twos complement.